# Unable to create sql context with hive support in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

In spark 1.6

After creating a soft link under /etc/spark/conf when I am running spark-shell it is not creating sql context with hive support and 
error---“native snappy library not available: This version of hadoop was built without snappysupport” is displayed.

Please advice what can be done here?

I am trying to create sql context with hive support but unable to do so.

Comment: Did you try this `val hiveContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)`

Comment: Did you try `sqlContext`, by default it comes with Hive support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqlContext` to access Hive tables.